# iOS 7/8 built-in method for posting to Facebook

Tags: ios, swift

I'm aware of the UIActivityViewController class in order to share/post to different things. But I have a Facebook button in my app that I want to directly popup a compose view without having to then select the Facebook icon on the UIActivityViewController. Is there a built-in way to do this without downloading Facebook's SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SLComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/) to present a Facebook compose sheet.

Comment: Awesome. Could I also use this for Message and Email sharing?

Comment: No, for those there are different controllers, namely `MFMailComposeViewController` and `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

Comment: Beat me to the answer, was adding example code - Consider adding to your answer?

Comment: @Wezly The API is very straightforward and simple, and there are examples on the internet. But feel free to edit if you have something ready.